# How to turn off default windows hotkeys using python?

Tags: python, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, pynput

I have a program that creates hotkeys for windows. For example win+s - open VSCode. It uses pynput to create these shortcuts. However, windows hotkeys are still working and, for example, when I try to create shortcut win+e to open program, it opens not only that program but also explorer, which is default windows hotkey. I've tried to find any information in google, but I've found nothing. Can you advise me a library or something to disable specific default windows shortcuts?

Comment: You want to disable hotkey using `pynput` or from `windows`? I have found article on how to disable hot in `windows`. But I am confused if you want to disable from `windows` or `pynput`.

Comment: I want to disable using python hotkey that windows uses and than use that key combination in pynput shortcut.